# How can I get scrolling to work for an NSCollectionView hosted in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, appkit, nsscrollview, nscollectionview

I've built an `NSCollectionView` wrapper using `NSViewRepresentable`, but it refuses to scroll. The class looks something like this:

```swift
final class SwiftNSCollectionView: NSObject, NSViewRepresentable, NSCollectionViewDataSource // etc
{
// ... init ...

    typealias NSViewType = NSCollectionView
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSCollectionView {
        let collectionView = NSCollectionView()
        scrollView.documentView = collectionView
        
        updateNSView(collectionView, context: context)
        
        return collectionView
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ scrollView: NSCollectionView, context: Context) {
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        // ... other collectionView setup
    }

    // ...
}
```

Typically, `NSCollectionView` has a built-in NSScrollView.

I've tried:

- No wrapper—the `NSCollectionView` simply doesn't scroll.
- Wrapping this `SwiftNSCollectionView` in a SwiftUI `ScrollView`, but that causes two problems:

  - The height of the the `NSCollectionView` collapses to 0 (which I can work around somewhat using a `GeometryReader`)
  - The `NSCollectionView` doesn't want to extend to the height of all its objects (which makes sense because it virtualizes them)
- Using `NSCollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration` with an orthogonal scroll direction (hacky):

  ```swift
  let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
  section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous

  // If the "official" scroll direction is horizontal,
  // then the orthogonal direction becomes vertical,
  // and we can scroll our one section 
  let configuration = NSCollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
  configuration.scrollDirection = .horizontal
  ```

  But this seemed to mess up keyboarding: after a certain number of elements, arrow keys between elements either stopped working altogether or moved to the completely wrong elements. Seemed like a virtualization bug of some sort.

Comment: is there exist some free access to your work with NSCollectionView hosted in SwiftUI? Possibly some github or sth else ?

Comment: Here's the hacky code I have. By weird luck I got it working for Ventura an hour ago. https://gist.github.com/citelao/e02850933268b80314bbbd4b1f000d9e

Comment: thanks a lot! You saved a hours of my work

Comment: thank you for asking OP! and thank you OP!

Comment: Could you please attach a license such as MIT to your Gist? @citelao thanks very much for sharing

Comment: I attached the MIT license; thanks for asking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mitigate this by creating an `NSScrollView` manually.

1. Update the `NSViewType` to be `NSScrollView`.
2. Update function signatures as required.
3. Use your existing `NSCollectionView` as the `.documentView` of the new scroll view.

Then you can use your `SwiftNSCollectionView` directly in SwiftUI code and it will scroll properly without any custom work on your side.

```swift
final class SwiftNSCollectionView: NSObject, NSViewRepresentable, NSCollectionViewDataSource // etc {
    // ... init ...

    // No longer NSCollectionView
    typealias NSViewType = NSScrollView
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSScrollView {
        // Create an NSScrollView, too!
        let scrollView = NSScrollView()
        let collectionView = NSCollectionView()
        scrollView.documentView = collectionView
        
        updateNSView(scrollView, context: context)
        
        return scrollView
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ scrollView: NSScrollView, context: Context) {
        // Since we get an NSScrollView, get the child!
        let collectionView = scrollView.documentView as! NSCollectionView
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        // ... other collectionView setup
    }

    // ...
}
```